# output irregularly and only a part of it is output

Tags: java

I want to get the input until there is no input, store the obtained value in the list, and output the list element.
However, the output value is output irregularly.

```
public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String s = input.nextLine();
        al.add(s);
    }
    input.close();
    
    for(String i:al) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I inputed as below.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sometimes, output

```
1
2
```

Sometimes, output

```
1
2
3
4
```

Sometimes, output

```
1
2
3
```

In this way, values are output irregularly. Sometimes all of them are print.

Comment: We don't know what input you're providing, so we can't really help you... the output will depend on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `Scanner` object to have a next item, you MUST pass the input to the System's input stream as declared when you initialized the object.  If you want to iterate through your `List` object, you need to use the list iterator's `hasNext()` method.

Also, the `Scanner#hasNext()` method will be blocked waiting for more input to be entered. If you were to step through your code in debug mode, you will see this. Therefore, after consuming your initial input, the program will "freeze". In my opinion, if you want to capture each word in the inputted line, break the `String` into tokens and iterate through the array of words.

---

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s = input.nextLine();
      input.close();

      List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+"));
      Iterator<String> iter = tokens.iterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
          al.add(iter.next());
      }
      System.out.println(al);
  }
```

---

```
INPUT: Mary had a little lamb
OUTPUT: [Mary, had, a, little, lamb]
```

**UPDATE**: I don't know why you deselected my answer as the correct answer, so let me answer your question again:  Why is the output "unstable"? The reason is because `Scanner#hasNext()` according the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())

> ***This method may block** while waiting for input to scan, **even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true**.*

Specifically for this code, it means that in this loop

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
    String s = input.nextLine();
    al.add(s);
}
```

At some point, these iterations will block, waiting for more input to be entered (captured). So, if you were to leave the code running forever, you may not see the `println()` function result while iterating through your array list. If you were to terminate the program, it will dump the collected results to the console, but most likely, you won't get the same result all the time. Therefore, I suggest you change your code to use an approach similar to the one I provided before in my answer.